# Django: Field.to_python not called on foreign key IDs?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've got a subclass of Field:

```
class MyIDField(Field):
    ...
    def to_python(self, value):
        return to_base_36(value)
```

And I use it as a primary key like this:

```
class Foo(m.Model):
    id = MyIDField(primary_key=True)

class Bar(m.Model):
    foo = m.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

Then the `MyIDField.to_python` function isn't called when I access `Bar.foo_id`:

```
>>> b = Bar.objects.all()[0]
>>> b.foo_id
1234
>>> b.foo.id
'ya'
>>>
```

This is annoying for a few reasons, but most significantly because it breaks dropdown menus in admin — they don't select the right values (the menu items *have* been `to_python`'d, but the default value has *not* been `to_python`'d).

Is this something I'm doing wrong? Or is this an issue with Django?

Comment: re: tags in titles. It's a convention I appreciate when I'm browsing questions, which is why I do it. However, if you can point me to community guidelines which discourage it, I'll be happy to stop.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update this: the bug has been accepted by Django, but no fix is in sight: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14518